# Will Google Play service update a running App?

Tags: android, auto-update

I am publishing an App on Google Play, which will need to update automatically.

The App is for a kiosk, and will therefore remain open and running for very long periods of time without the application ever being restarted for the nature or the device being rebooted.

My question: Will Google Play update an App which is currently running? 
Or the App must be stopped and restarted for an updated to take effect?
In my case, I would need Google Play to update an App while it is running and not wait for it to be restarted.

If the update only takes effect upon App restart is there code that I should put in my App to self check and execute an updated from Google Play?

Regards,
Joel

Comment: The Play Store does not update at all unless you manually authorize an update via the `Notification` or check the "automatic updates" checkbox. I am not certain of the precise behavior of the Play Store if you have the "automatic updates" checkbox checked.

Comment: Hi Andy, have you find a sollution for your update problem? I want to do the same thing basically and wonder how you solved the issue.