# onUpgrade race condition in running app

Tags: android, ormlite

we are using ormlite successfully in our android application; for maintaining database versions, we use an approach like here:
http://www.michenux.net/android-database-sqlite-creation-upgrade-245.html

Lately, we've seen "paranormal activity" in the field with apps being in databases states they could not "sanely be", and are trying to find explanations.

One could be that, when a *running* App is upgraded automatically by Google Play, the onUpgrade() is executed, changing tables and data, while the old (or the new?) App, or maybe their IntentServices concurrently access the database, and get strange results.

(Sadly, there is no easy way to just say "completely stop my app before upgrade, do the upgrade, then completely restart". There is the MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED intent, but opinions on how to use it greatly vary...)

So my question is, is there any safeguard in place that will make onUpgrade() run exclusively, i.e. blocking or locking or synchronizing anything, to make sure another thread does not access my table while I e.g. drop a column (i.e. rename, recreate, copy over data from old tab).

If no, how could I achieve such a thing in the safest way ?

Thanks & kind regards.

Comment: Weak hack here just to see if it would work, but you could try setting a static variable that you set to true when you are updating and false when done. You would need to make sure the upgrade process runs asynchronously. You could then check that flag before making any potentially corrupted requests. Doesn't seem ideal, but maybe?

Comment: Does Google Play not stop the app before attempting to upgrade it?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17794265/will-google-play-service-update-a-running-app. Unfortunately there is no answer ;-(

Comment: Do you by any chance have more than one instance of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` implementation?

Comment: We were able to reproduce the Problem and it indeed seems to be a race condition on app Start where onUpgrade modifies tables that are being read. I wonder if onUpgrade should't always be executed inside a BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION block...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so -

the thorough analysis exposed another (handmade) issue (in our code) that caused all those problems.

So, not to spread any rumours: It seems there is *no* race condition in onUpgrade() !

It would have been nice to know if it is good practice to have an (exclusive?) transaction block for onUpgrade(), though...
I do have one migration using begin transaction, und sqlite throws an error upon nested transactions, so I am pretty sure there is none around onUpgrade() automatically.

For clarification on other issues
Yes, Apps are terminated before being upgraded.
Only Services might need to re-read config, and alarms (timers) might need restarting.

Comment: Do you remember the issue that caused all those problems? I'm facing a very similar situation.